# sum statement in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

```
=======================================
Flight   SeatType   Price   GrandTotal
=======================================
F36712   Business   $480
         Economy    $375
         First      $450       ?

F12314   Business   $100
         Economy    $200
         First      $300       ?
```

I've tried this SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT FlightID,SeatType, sum(SeatPrice)Total
                  FROM seat 
                  WHERE SeatAvailable = 'Yes'
                  GROUP BY FlightID,SeatType, SeatPrice";
```

May I know how can I calculate the grand total (sum of the business, economy and first class for each flight)?

Comment: What do you mean by "GrandTotal" ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @Akinaru  Sum of the business,economy and first class for each flight

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MYSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you need the GrandTotal to be the Sum of all the business, economy and first class seats for each flight you can't have SeatType in the GROUP BY.

```
$sql = "SELECT FlightID, SUM(SeatPrice) AS Total
        FROM seat 
        WHERE SeatAvailable = 'Yes'
        GROUP BY FlightID";
```

Comment: but i need to display the quantity of the SeatType of each flight with the GrandTotal ....izit possible to do so ?

Comment: @Khai Yes, of course, it is but it helps to put your requirements clearly to begin with. Could you please update your question with the sample resultset you're expecting your query to receive?

Answer (score 1):

Your version of the query has `SeatPrice` in the `group by`.  This means that you are getting a separate row for each seat price.  I assume you want to get the total in each group of `SeatType`:

```
SELECT FlightID,SeatType, sum(SeatPrice) as Total
FROM seat 
WHERE SeatAvailable = 'Yes'
GROUP BY FlightID, SeatType with rollup;
```

However, that does not put the grand total in a separate column.  Once again, most versions of SQL support window functions to do this:

```
SELECT FlightID,SeatType, sum(SeatPrice) as Total,
       sum(sum(SeatPrice)) over (partition by FlightId)
FROM seat 
WHERE SeatAvailable = 'Yes'
GROUP BY FlightID, SeatType;
```

EDIT:

MySQL does not support window functions.  You can do the same with a join and aggregation:

```
SELECT s.FlightID, s.SeatType, sum(s.SeatPrice) as Total, f.GrandTotal
FROM seat s join
     (select FlightId, sum(SeatPrice) as GrandTotal
      from seat
      where SeatAvailable = 'Yes'
      group by FlightId
     ) f
     on s.FlightId = f.FlightId
WHERE s.SeatAvailable = 'Yes'
GROUP BY s.FlightID, s.SeatType;
```

Comment: Thx !!!!! u Help me to solve my problem !! Im very appreciated it....and i will learn more about it Thx again !=)

Comment: +1 for understanding the question better. I got caught up with OP's last line :)

Comment: F36712
Business 480 1305
Economy         375 1305
First         450 1305

can the grandtotal just display one time ? There not necessary to display repeatedly wor

Comment: Typically, to display the "grand total" once, you would use `rollup` and have it on a separate line.  In this case, you could put it conditionally on the "First" line, but that line might be filtered out, depending on seat availability.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  How can i do it ?